# Порядок выполнения классов в Codeigniter

Tags: ооп, php, codeigniter

В базовом контроллере **MyController** имею доступ к переменной из класса **Auth**

```
MyController extends Auth;
```

В классе **Auth** задается значение:

```
public $log = false;
```

В библиотеке пользовательской при попытке

```
var_dump($this->CI->isLogged);
```

Выдает **False**;

Не пойму, библиотеки что-ли раньше контроллеров грузятся? :)

---

Переменная $isLogged публичная и определена в классе **Auth.**

Класс **MyController** наследует класс **Auth**

Соответственно в классе **MyController** доступна и переопределяется переменная **$isLogged**, которую я хочу получить в пользовательской библиотеке

Comment: > Порядок выполнения классов

Классы именно что подключаются, выполняются функции.

> В классе Auth задается значение:

> public $log = false;
> В библиотеке пользовательской при попытке

> var_dump($this->CI->isLogged);

Как это связано?

> Не пойму, библиотеки что-ли раньше контроллеров грузятся? :)

Насколько понял по докам, нет.

Comment: На первый ваш вопрос я расширил описание проблемы в исходном вопросе

Comment: Так а что не так-то? Определения в классе либо наследуются как есть, либо перегружаются. При чем тут библиотек вообще?

Comment: $this->CI->isLogged - это что?
откуда у объекта CI такое свойство?
Может вам нужно $this->CI->ваша библиотеке->isLogged